# Trying to center footer links alongside some text

Tags: html, css, center, footer

I am trying to center footer links with some text near it. The text i can just use text-align but that won't work for the links. Anyone know a solution?

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/p7fxqmrc/1/

```
<footer>
    <p>Copyright 2014</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>



footer p{
    color:#5b5a5a;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:14px;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;

}

footer ul li{
    float:left;
    margin:10px;

}

footer ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#5b5a5a;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:14px;
    float:left;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynyhLk7/4/).

This is the updated CSS:

```
footer p {
    color:#5b5a5a;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:14px;
    margin:10px;
    text-align: center;
}
footer ul li {
    margin:10px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
footer ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#5b5a5a;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:14px;
}
footer ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Yea except i want the copyright to the left of the links with a small margin.